# Error on ListAdded event receiver

Tags: document-library, event-receivers

I have created a `List Event Receiver` to add a content type to every document library and added the following method :

```
    public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ListAdded(properties);
        this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
        if (properties.TemplateId == 101)
        {

            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    SPWeb web = properties.Web.Site.RootWeb;
                    SPList list = properties.List;
                    list.Title = list.Title + "-changed via code.";
                    list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

                    list.Update();

                    LoggingService.WriteLog(LoggingService.Category.Information, "======", "List title:" + list.Title);
                    SPContentType mzCT = web.ContentTypes["Documenten Content Type"];
                     if (mzCT != null)
                    {
                         if (list.ContentTypes["Documenten Content Type"] == null)
                        {
                           list.ContentTypes.Add(mzCT);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        this.EventFiringEnabled = true;

    }
```

It runs fine when I create the first document library, but then once I create a second document library, I get the following error:

```
Exception:    StackTrace:  
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op, Boolean isMigration, Boolean fResetCTCol)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldOnList(SPField field, Boolean bRecurAllowed)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldsOnList()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.DeriveContentType(SPContentTypeCollection cts, SPContentType& ctNew)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentTypeToList(SPContentType contentType)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentType(SPContentType contentType, Boolean updateResourceFileProperty, Boolean checkName, Boolean setNextChildByte)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.Add(SPContentType contentType, Boolean updateResourceFileProperty)    
 at MZOverpelt.WebTemplates.EventReceivers.DocumentsEventReceiver.DocumentsEventReceiver.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ListAdded>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at MZOverpelt.WebTemplates.EventReceivers.DocumentsEventReceiver.DocumentsEventReceiver.ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)   InnerException:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007047E): <nativehr>0x8007047e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd) Source:Microsoft.SharePoint
```

what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like adding a particular field to the list is giving the error.
By debugging and narrowing down you should find out which field this is. From there you can go forward.